# Capture the caption of the label clicked in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with few text boxes, combo boxes and label controls. I want to capture the caption of a label when it is clicked. The caption will be passed to a query which will create output on a different form.

I have tried Me.activecontrol.name but this seems to give the name of first text box and not the label which is clicked.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

A label cannot be active, so use the *OnClick* event of the label:

```
YourVariable = Me!YourLabel.Caption
```